# Скучать - по или за?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "скучать по кому-то" или "Скучать за кем-то"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Верно: *скучать по кому-чему* (с сущ. и личными местоимениями 3-го лица), *по ком-чём* (с личными местоимениями 1-го и 2-го лица мн. ч.: *скучаю по вас*). При этом второй вариант относится к старшей норме; младшая рекомендует во всех случаях употреблять с глаголом *скучать* форму дательного падежа. Кроме того, согласно словарю Ожегова—Шведовой или розенталевскому «Управление в русском языке», скучать можно *о ком-чём.*

А вот вариант *скучать за кем-либо* в русском языке не является нормативным.

Answer (score 1):

"Скучать по вас" -- устаревший вариант, сейчас чаще используется "скучать по вам"

Comment: Да он и раньше-то особо нормативным не был...